# Getting an error with Console.log('\x') in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

the problem occurs only when the word after the '\' begin with 'x'. I would like to know if \x is reserved word.

Comment: If you actually want to log the character `\ ` you need to escape it, as that character is the escape character in a string.  `\\ `.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a reserved word, it's a way to print a character by its code:

```
>>> console.log('\x56');
V
```

In fact, Firebug tells you what's wrong if you omit the number:

> SyntaxError: malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence

Like in many C-style languages, backslashes denote "escape sequences". More can be found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

Backslash is used to escape characters. If you need a literal backslash, use `\\`.